# Recursive contract that will infinitely call itself

Tags: solidity, evm

I want to create a contract so that when `eth_call` is called, the contract returns EVM error: [CallTooDeep](https://docs.rs/evm/latest/evm/enum.ExitError.html#variant.CallTooDeep)

Tried something like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract CallTooDeep {
    function test() public {
        address(this).test();
    }
}
```

But gets an error:

```
TypeError: Member "test" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address.
 --> contracts/CallTooDeep.sol:6:9:
  |
6 |         address(this).test();
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

How I can fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just call the function by its name if there is no imported interface providing the function.

try this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract CallToDeep {
    function test() public {
       CallToDeep(address(this)).test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

gasLimit: 29,900,000, 453 Internal Transactions https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xa4e15670efd5d966cce73b807292524f11810bfc5cba9cb08c52de6982d68b89

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract CallTooDeep {
    function test() public {
       CallTooDeep(address(this)).test();
    }
}
```

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_call",
    "params": [
        {
            "data": "0xf8a8fd6d",
            "to": "0xc20a1e280ab7786d718eb38b062b9004943d9eee"

        },
        "latest"
    ],
    "id": 2
}
```

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 2,
    "error": {
        "code": -32000,
        "message": "execution reverted"
    }
}
```

https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x19c6ef37e7490b19f60b851de85d4a4b0fb472a9445502769f537d8e8ebb0a2e

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract CallToDeep {
    function test() public {
       CallToDeep.test();
    }
}
```

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_call",
    "params": [
        {
            "data": "0xf8a8fd6d",
            "to": "0x26538b1453083081c8180f2600261ddc61730846"

        },
        "latest"
    ],
    "id": 2
}
```

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 2,
    "error": {
        "code": -32000,
        "message": "stack limit reached 1024 (1023)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your function `test()` before it can be called.